# How to get Firestore data of similar date?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching all data using this query:

```
val topicRef = DatabaseReferenceManager.getTopicsCoverdReference().whereEqualTo("batchId", batchId)
```

And want to sort same date data from the data i am fetching.

[image]

I am trying get data of similar date of uploading data to firestore.data which is stored on same date.

```
topics_array.forEach {
    if (i == 0) {
        date_object.date = topic_object.date
        date_object_array.add(date_object)

        Toast.makeText(this, "" + date_object_array.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else if (topic_object.date == date_object.date) {
        date_object.topics.add(topic_object.topic)
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + date_object_array.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        topic_array?.add(date_object)
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + topic_array!!.size, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    i++
    topic_array = null
    date_object.date = topic_object.date
    date_object.topics.add(topic_object.topic)
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + topic_array, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

This is how i am trying to compaire two dates.to find if similar date found in data,that should passed to arraylist and then set that araylist to recycler

Comment: What do you mean by "similar date data"? Besides that, please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to get data which is updated on same date.

Comment: Piese edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: @AlexMamo cant add image directly as i dont have reputation 10.but have given link of my database image please check that out

Comment: @AlexMamo plz see if you can hep me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the last update data you can do it by:

- Setting a new field called updatedDate and then make a query [sorting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) the dates and retrieve the last updated.
- Listening for [realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) with the method onSnapshot():